# Амплитудный и фазовый спектры аудио сигнала

Tags: matlab

Здравствуйте. Необходимо построить графики амплитудного и фазового спектров wav - файла. Можно ли это сделать с помощью следующей команды:

```
T = 5; 
tay=0.01;
t = 0 : tay : T;
f0=1/T;
x=wavread('C:\1.wav');
max=1/2*tay;
N=length(x);
fmax=-max:abs((2*max)/(N-1)):max;
A=fftshift(fft(x));   
plot(fmax, abs(A)); %амплитудный спектр
plot(fmax, angle(A)); %фазовый спектр
grid on;
```

По оси Ох частоты в Гц, по оси Оу - что?

Answer (score 1):

Амплитуда  и  фаза сигнала :-)

Answer (score 0):

Амплитуда в относительных единицах (она, например, зависит от дискретности исходного сигнала и промежутка обработки), фаза в радианах